# How to get destination url from multiple time redirecting url in python?

Tags: python-3.x, redirect, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to make a web scraper. I would like to get the destination URL from a query URL. But it redirects many times.

This is my URL:

```
https://data.jw-api.org/mediator/finder?lang=INS&item=pub-jwb_201812_16_VIDEO
```

Destination url should be:

```
https://www.jw.org/ins/library/videos/#ins/mediaitems/VODOrgLegal/pub-jwb_201812_16_VIDEO
```

But I am getting `https://www.jw.org/ins/library/videos/?item=pub-jwb_201812_16_VIDEO&appLanguage=INS` this as the redirected URL.

I tried this code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://data.jw-api.org/mediator/finder?lang=INS&item=pub-jwb_201812_16_VIDEO'

s = requests.get(url)
print(s.url)
```

Answer (score 1):

The redirect is made using JavaScript

It is not a server redirect so requests is not following it.

You can get the URL using Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://data.jw-api.org/mediator/finder?lang=INS&item=pub-jwb_201812_16_VIDEO'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
print (browser.current_url)
browser.quit()
```

Outputs

```
https://www.jw.org/ins/library/videos/#ins/mediaitems/VODOrgLegal/pub-jwb_201812_16_VIDEO
```

If you are building a scraper I would suggest you check out scrapy-splash https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash or requests-html https://github.com/psf/requests-html

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But the problem with Selenium is that it requires webdriver such as Chromedriver, Firefoxdriver... If I am making this script as an executable and installing it on another computer that computer too require webdriver. Is there any solution other than Selenium?

Comment: You could look at PyQt in particular QWebEngineView there are many examples on the internet of how to do basic rendering of web pages using JavaScript for it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will check.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily using requests:

```
import requests
destination = requests.get("http://doi.org/10.1080/07435800.2020.1713802") 
#this link redirects the user to another link with a research paper of a given DOI code
print(destination.url)
#this returns "https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/07435800.2020.1713802", the redirect of the initial doi.org link
```

Comment: I've tried this when there are two redirects and it doesn't work; 
It gives you the url of the first redirect, not the last. 

TLDR only works with 1 redirect.